# Pandas crosstab with top elements

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have dataframe with two columns like following:

```
| index | class1 | class2 |
|-------|--------|--------|
| 0     | a      | z      |
| 1     | a      | z      |
| 2     | a      | y      |
| 3     | b      | x      |
| 4     | b      | y      |
| 5     | b      | x      |
| 6     | c      | z      |
| 7     | c      | z      |
| 8     | c      | x      |
```

I want to calculate statistics by one class over two. In the result I expect the table with one class as rows, second class as columns and values at the intersection. In my case may be large class count as in `class1` and in `class2`. So in columns should be only tops class2 objects in the corresponding class 1

As example output:

```
|   | a    |   | b    |   | c    |
|---|------|---|------|---|------|
| x | 0    |   | 0.33 |   | 0.33 |
|   |      |   |      |   |      |
| y | 0.33 |   | 0.33 |   | 0    |
|   |      |   |      |   |      |
| z | 0.66 |   | 0.33 |   | 0.66 |
```

I like to do these using `crosstab` func:

```
pd.crosstab(index=df['class1'],
            columns=df['class2'],
            normalize='index')
```

The question:

How to leave only top class2 classes by all class1 classes? Also are the any ideas how to do aggregation except croostab?

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there, you don't want to normalize over `index` but over `columns`:

```
dfn = pd.crosstab(index=df['class2'],
                  columns=df['class1'],
                  normalize='columns').round(2)

print(dfn)
class1     a     b     c
class2                  
x       0.00  0.67  0.33
y       0.33  0.33  0.00
z       0.67  0.00  0.67
```

To remove index and column names:

```
dfn = (pd.crosstab(index=df['class2'],
                   columns=df['class1'],
                   normalize='columns')
       .round(2)
       .rename_axis(None)
       .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
      )
print(dfn)
      a     b     c
x  0.00  0.67  0.33
y  0.33  0.33  0.00
z  0.67  0.00  0.67
```

Comment: Thanks, Erfan! Are there any ideas how to get only top classes (for example if class2 contains 10 classes and a from class1 contains only two from them)?